# Why should one use React with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm new to both Meteor and React and I didn't see the importance of using one with the other.

What features React provides that doesn't exist in Meteor ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React uses a different approach on building and managing UI interfaces.

For example Blaze uses jQuery to manipulate the DOM directly, while react.js is working on a virtual DOM (unattached) and when there is an update it diffs the actual & virtual DOMs and updates only the parts that differ, to make the actual DOM reflect the changes.

The big advantage of react is that you can construct reusable UI components (something similar to [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)).

I would very much suggest reading this great **[article on react & meteor](http://blog.percolatestudio.com/engineering/reactive-user-interfaces/)**

### Update 03.02.2016

The guys from Kadira, who are well versed in meteor and offer professional tooling for meteor, say that **react is the way**. They also [published a mantra](https://voice.kadira.io/sneak-peek-mantra-7161624acaa7#.f0jxbo8nx) - which is basically a blueprint on how to build proper meteor apps. I suggest reading into it

Comment: Two of the greatest features of React vs simply using blaze are (1) the fact that React has a very rich community where you can get ready made networks of components designed to work together. And (2) a very clear difference between component state and reactive component state.  And being able to draw clear lines between the two, having the state of your component properly behave in response to a reactive variable change from Meteor.  You can even expand on that idea with things like redux.  Not to mention using React Router and a bunch of other excellent constructions. React+Meteor is awesome